# Python LDAP3 get empty result

Tags: python, ldap

I have the following code which prints maxPwdAge, objectGUID, and name but conn.entries is returning an empty set, anything I am missing in this code?

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, Tls
import ssl

# LDAP server connection settings
ldap_server = 'ldaps://SERVER_FQDN:636'
ldap_user = 'USERNAME'
ldap_password = 'PASSWORD'
ldap_base_dn = 'DC=AA,DC=BB,DC=CC'  # highest level in the domain

# Establish LDAPS connection
server = Server(ldap_server, use_ssl=True, tls=Tls(validate=ssl.CERT_NONE))
conn = Connection(server, user=ldap_user, password=ldap_password)
conn.bind()

# Search for entries and retrieve attributes
conn.search(ldap_base_dn, '(objectClass=*)', attributes=['objectGUID', 'maxPwdAge', 'name'])
# tried to search objectClass top, added a filter to "CN=" + DOMAIN_NAME + ",CN=Partitions,CN=Configuration," + ldap_base_dn but it did not work
# Extract attribute values from the search results
if conn.entries:
    for entry in conn.entries:
        object_guid = entry.objectGUID.value
        max_pwd_age = entry.maxPwdAge.value
        name = entry.name.value

        # Print the retrieved values
        print("Object GUID:", object_guid)
        print("Max Password Age:", max_pwd_age)
        print("Name:", name)

# Unbind and close the connection
conn.unbind()
```

Comment: We don't know anything about the structure of your ldap server so it's impossible for us to tell whether there is a problem with your code, with your credentials, or with your base DN. Does the same search work successfully when you use something like `ldapsearch` on the command line?

Comment: `conn.search` seems to (based on the examples [here](https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial_searches.html)) return a boolean value telling you if it succeeded, so check the return value. If it's `false`, then you know something went wrong, and you can check for an error message in `conn.result`, as defined here: https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/connection.html#result

Comment: I also suggest you add `search_scope=BASE` to your search, so it only looks at the root object of the domain, and not every object on your domain.